# Illegal character in authority for PostgreSql connection string

Tags: java, python, postgresql

My connection string to Postgresql which I'm using in my app:

```
let dsn = "postgresql://me:somepassword$@localhost/my_db";
```

The error is

```
Connection error: Invalid connection parameters: Illegal character in authority'
```

What's invalid in it? is it "$"? But that's a part of my password.

Comment: what has this got to do with java?

Comment: @ScaryWombat, it's used from my java app.

Answer (score 0):

> Answer referenced from:
>
> https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/80/connect.html

It seems that your PostgreSQL URL has the wrong syntax.

I do not know which method you are using to connect to the database, but assuming that you are using JDBC to connect, the syntax should be something like this:

```
"jdbc:postgresql://host:port/database?user=username&password=password"
```

General postgresql URL example for your case:

```
"postgresql://localhost:5432/my_db?user=me&password=somepassword$"
```

> What's invalid in it? is it "$"? But that's a part of my password.

If you follow the syntax of my sample URL, the "$" should have no issues. Please try it out because I am also interested in the outcome.